# Gatsby: GraphQL Cannot query field \"allMarkdownRemark\" on type \"Query\"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, filesystems, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm new to Gatsby and attempting to build blog functionality. I have installed `gatsby-source-filesystem`, `gatsby-transformer-remark`, and `gatsby-plugin-catch-links`. I have blog posts within the `pages` directory, each blog post is within a folder inside `pages`. When I attempt to query the blog posts witin `pages` I can the following error:

`Cannot query field \"allMarkdownRemark\" on type \"Query\"`

Here's how my project is structured:

[image]

Here is my config file:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Crash Course`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-catch-links`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

My GraphQL query :

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          path
          title
          date 
          author
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this error and get `allMarkdownRemark` to work properly and retrieve the blog posts from `pages`?

Comment: Can you provide your query?

Comment: I restarted gatsby and now allMarkdownRemark works, but I'm getting an error retrieving the frontmatter. I will add the query right now.

Comment: Keep in mind to restart your `gatsby develop` every time you change a query. Can you share more information about the error?

Comment: Restarting fixed the initial issue with allMarkdownRemark. The second issue was due to my frontmatter being written wrong in my md file. Thanks for the help, I got things working.